# Terraform. Access the current Oracle Cloud tenancy specified by provider

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have an OCI provider for my Terraform script:

```
provider "oci" {
    region = "eu-frankfurt-1"
}
```

Where all the attributes are defined over environment variables [as specified by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/terraformproviderconfiguration.htm#securityTokenAuth).

```
export TF_VAR_tenancy_ocid=...
export TF_VAR_user_ocid=...
```

Other elements of the scripts requires an ID of the tenancy. It there a way to get the ID or the current tenancy  without reading an environment variables again?

AWS provider for Terraform allows to reference the current account as:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

output "account_id" {
   value = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
}
```

It there something similar for OCI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since tenancy ID is already set in environment variable TF_VAR_tenancy_ocid you just need to declare a variable:

```
variable "tenancy_ocid" {
   description = "Tenancy OCID"
}
```

Make sure that the variable name above exactly matches with whatever is present after TF_VAR_

Terraform automatically set the values of these variables using environment variables set using TF_VAR_*variable-name*

Then you can use the value like below:

```
output "account_id" {
   value = var.tenancy_ocid
}
```

You can also look for data sources in the terraform oci provider docs [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/oci/latest/docs/data-sources/identity_tenancy)